# Hide element via css when another element is present on the page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to hide an element if one element is already present on the page.

If element with the id:

```
#wcfmmp_store_about
```

is present on the page, then hide following element:

```
.left_sidebar.widget-area.sidebar
```

So I've found a solution how to do this via js. but **I need to this via .css**, if possible

```
var element =  document.getElementById('wcfmmp_store_about');

if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
 document.querySelector('.left_sidebar.widget-area.sidebar').style.display = "none";
} else {
 document.querySelector('.left_sidebar.widget-area.sidebar').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: CSS can do quite a bit these days but you need javascript for this.

Comment: I see. The issue is that the page is being access from different domain name, so for some reason, it doesn't read the javascript code. Is there any way around this? Maybe to add through .php function?

Comment: You could use PHP if you have access to a MySQL database but I would try to resolve the js issue. Can you contact your host?

Comment: @MarkoI. Please check my answer again as I've added a few more things to cover some more bases and to explain that this is not a full proof method.  I still would agree with SJacks and say JS is the better method to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can kind of do this. Here's an example, but it is not full proof though.

This only works if `.tohide` follows directly after `.item` or if `.tohide` follows `.item` as a sibling.

```css
.item + .tohide {
  display: none;
}

.item ~ .tohide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="tohide">I show up when item is gone</div>
```

So in this example, if `.item` exists on the page, then `.tohide` is hidden.  Go ahead and remove `<div class="item">item</div>` and run it and you will see that `.tohide` appears now. You can play with it in this jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/qzu7hkcg/1/

Comment: It won't work if the other element is just hidden so it's not a full solution. js is the ideal here.

Comment: I agree, JS is the better solution, but this is a somewhat form of a hack which is pure CSS.